# Detect changes in label and call function when its content changes

Tags: swift

I am doing a project with beacons and I have a problem. The idea is that when detecting a beacon, a predefined text appears in a label and that this text is automatically added to a table which will register all the beacons with which I come across.

The beacon recognition is done but, when adding the label text to the table automatically, "infinite" values are added, when the idea is that it is only added once whenever the value of that text changes.

Is there a way to detect changes in a label and only call the function once when the value changes?

I am using CoreLocation for the beacon issue, in case it was necessary to know.

The function to add values is:

```
func addBeacon(){
        
            guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
                //generating a new key inside beacons node
                //and also getting the generated key
            let key = refBeacons.childByAutoId().key
                
            
            let date = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .short, timeStyle: .medium)
           // Set output format

                
                //creating beacon with the given values
            let places = ["place": prueba.text! as String,
                          "date":date
                                
            ] as [String : Any]
            
                //adding the beacon inside the generated unique key
            refBeacons.child(user.uid).child("places").child(key!).setValue(places)
                
                //displaying message
                labelMessage.text = "Beacon Added"

        }
```

And the func to detect beacons is:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        if beacons.count > 0 {
            for beacon:CLBeacon in beacons {
                if beacon.proximity == CLProximity.far {
                // Far away, whatever than means
                } else if beacon.proximity == CLProximity.near {
                    
                    if beacons.first?.proximityUUID.uuidString == "15164A5A-F607-49AE-0000-66B7106A0000" {
                        prueba.text = "Tracking beacon: \"MyBeacon 1\""
                        addBeacon()

                        stopScanningF()
                        stopScanningE()
                        
                        
                        if isDetectedE == false {
                                
  
                        }
                    }
                    if beacons.first?.proximityUUID.uuidString == "74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059100" {
                        prueba.text = "Tracking beacon: \"MyBeacon 2\""
                        addBeacon()

                        stopScanningF()
                        stopScanningE()
                        
                        
                        if isDetectedF == false {

                           
                        }
                    }
                // Getting closer
                } else if beacon.proximity == CLProximity.immediate {
                // Right on top of the beacon
              }
            }
          } else {
            // No beacons found
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it, I leave the answer below in case someone could be useful.

I did it by observer and instead of label I used a textview.

In the viewDidLoad() I added

```
textView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
```

Then I added the following functions

```
func startObservingTextView() {
        textView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(rawValue: 0), context: nil)
    }

    func stopObservingTextView() {
        textView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text")
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        if change?[.oldKey] as! String != change?[.newKey] as! String {

            addBeacon()//function that adds the values

        }

    }
```